# Set default Built-in Audio in KDE

Tags: 12.04, sound, kde4

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and using KDE for primary my DE alongside Unity. my problem is audio always detect HDMI for default. so when I'd turned down the volume on my laptop, it did not happen. while the standard setting for sound on my laptop is a Built-in Stereo Analogan not  Audio Digital Audio Stereo (HDMI). how to change the order Built-in Analog Audio Stereo became standard on KDE.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes,I may help to solve this.

1. Right click the Kmix icon, click Select Master Channel.
2. In the current mixer,choose your Built-in Stereo Analogan.

Answer (score 0):

yes but then on next startup it's HDMI again ! KDE seems to have a lot of problems remembering settings. (panel width changes alot)